# How to merge 2 transactions in one?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

First of all, I have already searched on Google, and I didn't find a clear answer.

**What I would like to do :**
For example, I would like to make one swap on uniswap, and the second to sushiswap, **in the same transaction**, like this :

UNISWAP : ETH -> UNI

SUSHISWAP : UNI ( last output ) -> ALCX

I know it's possible by writing a smart contract, but I don't know at all how to do.
Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: @SergiJuanati , Hello, not exactly, I already saw this post before.
In my mind , it should be like this :

1 - Send ETH to the contract
2 - Call UniwapRouter, to swap theses ETH against UNI ( for example )
3 - Call SushiswapRouter to swap these UNI against ALCD ( for example )
4 - End

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make two swaps in a single transaction without going through a smart contract.

Uniswap and Sushiswap are 2 different contracts and the only way to interact with both in a single transaction is through a smart contract.

Comment: hello, I know it , as I said "  I know it's possible by writing a smart contract, but I don't know at all how to do "

Comment: Then you have to learn how to develop smart contracts. Have a look at this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/95081/recommended-approach-to-becoming-a-developer-in-the-space/95115#95115