# As a CS student, where should I start to learn Ethereum development?

Tags: dapp-development

I'm a cs student looking to learn ethereum development. I'm very confused about all the things I need to learn.
Smart contracts are programmed in solidity but if I want to build any kind of app I will need a frontend right?
So learning solidity alone is completely useless ?

Do I have to start with a full web dev course? And learn HTML, CSS, js ?
What would be the fastest way to learn eth dev and be able to make a portfolio to someday get a job?

I already have coding knowledge mainly in c++  and also know some computer science

But never did web dev

Can anyone help me with a roadmap?

I alredy know some Algorithms/Data Structures and coding in c++ from college

Comment: Hi! You might want to check out this question and the answers there: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/95081/68501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be a "full stack" Ethereum developer, and you cannot rely on the help of other team members, this is the body of knowledge you need to minimally know

- Front-end JavaScript to write user interfaces and interact with MetaMask
- HTML, a necessary frontend basic skill
- CSS, a necessary frontend basic skill
- Modern JavaScript frameworks like React and their tooling
- Solidity
- Any Ethereum development framework like Brownie, Hardhat
- Node.js: needed to interact with frontend Ethereum toolchains like Hardhat and React builders
- Unit testing, integration testing, continuous integration best practices
- Unix command line (needed for tooling). Although a lot of tooling is available on Windows, professional developers prefer macOS or Linux. Thus, you need to know your way around Bash or other Unix shell. Install a Linux on your local computer or start learning linux in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)

All together it is around two-three years of curriculum for a person without any prior experience in the listed areas above, but with prior experience in professional software development. Probably more than three years if you want to be a professional. For a person without prior experience in programming, I would say learning the basic skills to become a professional takes five years.

Where to start? I would start learning basic web development to the point I can get data out from MetaMask to my web frontend. After that, I would try to create my first smart contract that interacts with my web frontend. Also web frontend development skills are usable outside the Ethereum world, so those skills have a higher likelihood for learning investment return.

Comment: Great answer. I’m curious what it takes to be a core developer. Also, would like to add there are different areas of focus if you wish to get into Dapps such as defi or Nft or analytics.

Comment: The answer applies to any Dapp development. For "core" development, by this meaning working on the blockchain clients itself like Go Ethereum or OpenEthereum, you need a system-programmer skillset and it is different from the above. Cryptography, theoretical CS, backend scalable programming.